# How to redirect web traffic to specific host with iptables

Tags: iptables, iptables-redirect

I want to be able to redirect a host in my Lan to an specific ip address and port. I can achieve one thing which is that only  my desired host can access the ip address, but I can't get the user to redirect when they type something in their url bar. I will show you the steps I've taken to accomplish this

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.3:5000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

#The address below is the host I'm redirecting 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.2.14 -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.3:5000
```

Please let me know how can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this setup:

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.3:5000
iptables -t nat -A SRCNAT -j MASQUERADE
```

You can see more examples [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/easy-setup-of-iptables-on-your-new-linux-server.html).
It should work, but why are you trying implement at firewall level anyway?

If you have a webserver at your host 192.168.2.14 why don't you just add redirect to the right address at your .htaccess, for example?
It will be the easiest and robust way to do, I can highly recommend it instead.